# Make a field required in the controller when errors are returned from web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, modelstate

I need to make an number of fields required but only when errors are posted back from a web api.

so far I have managed to add the errors to the ModelState using this code:

```
if (model.ApplicationValidations != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in model.ApplicationValidations.Select((validationMessage) => new {validationMessage}))
            {
                if (item.validationMessage.URL == "http://localhost:64026/mba-application/apply/personal-details/")
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("required fields", item.validationMessage.FieldName + " is required");
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there a way of using ModelState to make a field required within the controller, if not how do I go about making the fields I want required (because the web api is doing the validation I cannot use the [Required] attribute)